# Sending task to specific folder in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

In tasks view, I have created several Task folders. When I create a follow-up, it is created in "To-do list" by default. I have to manually move it to the specific task folder.

Isn't there a way to make Outlook ask me which Task folder the task will be created, instead of creating it under "To-do list" all the time ??

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this using Outlook's native functionality.

You may need to write some custom VBA code (macro) to do achieve this.

One option is to to [write event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa209965%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for the TaskItem.Write event and the TaskItem.BeforeAutoSave event. This would prompt you to choose a folder to save to, when either you save the task, or when Outlook tries to autosave it.

Another option would be to [modify the Task form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868929%28v=office.14%29.aspx), so that there is a drop down list of folders to choose from. For example, this could be under the Subject field. Then when you create a task, you could choose which folder to save it to without a prompt.

Either method would involve writing VBA code.